# App keeps closing -csv file - Android studio - updated

Tags: android

For some reason when I click my create shopping list button my app stops. What its suppose to do is go to the new screen and show a list view with the data imported from a csv.

I opened a new project and just put this code into mainactivity.java and activity_mainxml, without any buttons or backgrounds or other screens and my csv showed up correctly. So is it something wrong with how i'm transferring the code?

My code below:

**create.java**

```
package com.app.supermarketaislefinder;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class create extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);
        CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);
        List<String[]> foodList = csvFile.read();
        MyListAdapter adapter=new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow,R.id.txtid, foodList);
        ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class CSVFile {
        InputStream inputStream;

        public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream){
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        public List<String[]> read(){
            //
            List<String[]> resultList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] row = line.split(",");
                    resultList.add(row);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main",e.getMessage());
            }
            finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Main",e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return resultList;
        }
    }





}
```

**My List Adapter**

```
package com.app.supermarketaislefinder;

import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String[]>{
    int groupid;
    List<String[]> items;
    Context context;
    String path;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int vg, int id, List<String[]> items){
        super(context,vg, id, items);
        this.context=context;
        groupid=vg;
        this.items=items;

    }
    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textid;
        public TextView textname;

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = convertView;
        if(rowView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView= inflater.inflate(groupid, parent, false);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.textid = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.aisle);
            viewHolder.textname = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        // Fill data
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        String[] row=items.get(position);
        holder.textid.setText(row[0]);
        holder.textname.setText(row[1]);

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

**activity_create.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".create"
    android:background="@drawable/createbackground"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="384dp"
        android:layout_height="117dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorCreate"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/appTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fontFamily="@font/bree_serif"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Create your Shopping List"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="34sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
        android:layout_width="384dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorCreateSub"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout">

    </LinearLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout6"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**list_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: StackOverFlow is not a code writing service. Come back with a problem and post your code

Comment: updated the post

Comment: Updated it - found a solution but got an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out I put the wrong xml name.

Before:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

After:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
```

Woops!